# Using Durandal dojoConfig and ESRI Maps

Tags: dojo, durandal, esri

I'm trying to get ESRI maps working with Durandal and came across this link in the Durandal docs  [DurandalEsri](https://github.com/dgwalton/DurandalEsri)

This seems to work but now Durandal is having problems finding some of my .js files. If I leave the following dojoConfig out my scripts are found but then the maps won't work.

```
`var dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: './',
    async: true,
    tlmSiblingOfDojo: true,
    parseOnLoad: false,
    aliases: [['text', 'dojo/text']],
    packages: [
        { name: 'esri', location: '//serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri' },
        { name: 'dojo', location: '//serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/dojo/dojo' },
        { name: 'dojox', location: '//serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/dojo/dojox' },
        { name: 'dijit', location: '//serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/dojo/dijit' },
        { name: 'durandal', location: 'App/durandal' },
        { name: 'views', location: 'App/views' },
        { name: 'viewmodels', location: 'App/viewmodels' },
        { name: 'lib', location: 'App/lib' }
    ]
};`
```

My app structure looks like this:

- App

  - durandal
  - lib
  - services
  - viewmodels
  - views

So in my shell.js file if I try to pass in 'lib/config' I get a 404 because it tried to find the config file at localhost/lib/config.js instead of localhost/dashboard/app/lib/config.js

If I pass 'dashboard/app/lib/config' to shell.js the file will be found, but it doesn't seem like I should have to specify the entire path, since 'durandal/system' and anything else under the 'durandal' folder get found correctly.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for my scenario of Durandal + Esri + Dojo,  I had to leave out the require.js file that is included with Durandal and use the dojo AMD loader.  Unfortunately I have no idea what future problems this might cause.
 More info can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/PlPq9uyT618)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem using AMD module loading with Esri. I solved it using a configuration similar to yours but with the following baseurl:

`baseUrl: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') + '/path/to/app/main'`

As described in Jeffrey Grajkowski's answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390919/1014822

Comment: I kinda got it to work using your method, but for some reason I had to add a extra "/App" to the path  ...+'/App/App'   I also had to use the modified dojo.js from the link in my question

Comment: Not sure why it would need the additiona `App` but glad you have it working.

Comment: I ran into some more problems when I tried to integrate the changes to my actual app.  In my app we explicitly load require.js like this:   <script type="text/javascript" src="/App/durandal/amd/require.js"
     data-main="/App/main"></script>when I do this its searching for the esri files on local host and getting a 404.  I'm guessing when I don't include durandals require.js it ends up using the dojo AMD