# XPages 9 with Esri maps dojo conflict: 'defineAlreadyDefined'

Tags: dojo, xpages, esri

With our update to XPages version 9 and the Esri ARcgis javascript api v 3.5, we're having problems with our dojo namespaces resulting in a defineAlreadyDefined error.  There are a few similar problems listed here ([Using Durandal dojoConfig and ESRI Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927104/using-durandal-dojoconfig-and-esri-maps), [How can I fix this AMD path conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386284/how-can-i-fix-this-amd-path-conflict/15390919#15390919)), but even with that help we are unable to get it working. I believe the issue is the dojoConfig syntax - any thoughts or help would be appreciated!

Here is a simple version of our xpage source code with js:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:this.resources>
 <xp:styleSheet
  href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
 </xp:styleSheet>
 <xp:styleSheet
  href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri/css/esri.css">
 </xp:styleSheet>
 <xp:script clientSide="true">
 // dojo.registerModulePath("esri","http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri");

 dojoConfig = {
  baseUrl: "http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri", 
  packages: [
   {
    name: 'dojo',
    location: "http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/dojo/dojo/"
   },
   {
     name: 'dojox',
     location: "http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/dojo/dojox"
   },
   { 
     name: 'esri',
     location: "http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri"
    }
   ]};
 </xp:script>
  <xp:script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/"
            clientSide="true">
  </xp:script>    
  <xp:dojoModule name="esri.map"></xp:dojoModule>
 </xp:this.resources>
 <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var map;
    function init(){
     var map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {
        center: [-56.049, 38.485],
        zoom: 3,
        basemap: "streets"
      });
    }
    dojo.ready(init);

   ]]></xp:this.script>
```

If we include the dojo.registerModulePath command, the map does load (at least in FF), but with the error.  Without it, the esri dojo doesn't load - it's looking in the wrong place for the esri files.

Comment: What happens if you remove dojo and dojox from Packages? XPages already loads dojo/dojox (unless you disable it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was a problem for me too!
I've been able to get it working by using the following code:

```
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script clientSide="true">
            dojo.registerModulePath("esri","http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri");
            dojoConfig = { baseUrl: "http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri",
            packages: [ { name: 'esri', location: "http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri" } ]};
        </xp:script>
        <xp:styleSheet href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css" />
        <xp:styleSheet href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/dijit/css/Popup.css" />
  <xp:dojoModule name="esri.map"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var map;
    function init(){
     var map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {
        center: [0,53],
        zoom: 10,
        basemap: "streets"
      });
    }
    dojo.ready(init);

   ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <div id="mapDiv" style="width:1000px;height:600px"></div>
    </xp:view>
```

I think the order of scripts is important and you don't need to include the esri.map script twice.

Answer (score 3):

There are few things you need to keep in mind, and probably change the code accordingly:

- xPages already makes use of dojoconfig, either through xsp-config
  file options or using xPages parameters.
- As mentioned by Per, dojo is already used in xPages, so you don't need to load it from somewhere else (same applies to the CSS).

What you can do is following:

- Option 1: Use offline copies of JS library for maps. You can add them
  to your xPages app as JS resources. You will only have to specify
  them in your xPage, and load dojo module as you do already;
- Option 2: See below how to inject more dojoConfig options before a xPage will load

Code:

```
<xp:this.properties>
    <xp:parameter name="xsp.client.script.dojo.djConfig" value="packages: exPackages" />
</xp:this.properties>
<xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        var response = exCon.getResponse();
        var writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write("<script>\n");
        writer.write("var exPackages=[{name:'esri',location:'http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/js/esri'}]\n");
        writer.write("</script>\n");
        }]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="esri.map"></xp:dojoModule>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Update: Small correction of code.

Update2: After briefly checking ArcGis website, it seems they choose to provide Dojo together with their API (which is wrong in my opinion). See https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/inside_dojoversion.html (part2), although it will not help you much as they don't provide a feasible solution for Dojo 1.8.x

Seeing that their API is not free, I think the best way would be to contact them, ask for  ESRI part of the API as separate download, host it on your own servers and follow either Option 1 or 2. Moreover, the version of API you try to use is based on Dojo 1.8.3, while Domino 9 has Dojo 1.8.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  We had put in a ticket with ESRI too, and they are not able to either figure out how to remap or provide a version of the API that does not have dojo embedded.  As you say, it is not quite the same version either, although probably xpages would work just fine with 1.8.3. We will try to make it work with your option 2.